# How can i execute functions with respective sql operation insert and update

Tags: c#, mysql

I am inserting and updating data from on db table to another db table. For this i have 2 functions. I want that control should go to function based on sql operation.

If i inserted data in a db table then control should go to insert function, if i update the db table data then control should go to update function.

Can some one help how can i wrote conditions here to achieve this.

Many Thanks

C# code

```
//When service starts controls comes to this block
public ESS_VMint()
{
   dLib = new DataLibrary("ESS", false, out essStatus);
   dLib = new DataLibrary("VillageMate", false, out villagemateStatus);

   InsertFields();
   UpdateFields();
}

public DataTable InsertFields()
{
    //Insert operations
}

public DataTable UpdateFields()
{
   //Update Operations
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what you mean. It sounds like you want to control whether InsertFields() or UpdateFields() is executed depending on some criteria. Is that correct? I guess the user interface will supply some value which tells you which type of operation is required? Or are you hoping that the code will automatically know somehow? If you are passing in an object from the UI, perhaps you can check if it already has an ID - if so then (assuming you use an auto-increment ID field in you DB for the ID) that would mean it already exists, so the operation needs to be an Update.

Comment: You can use primary key or identity to decide, If primary key is 0 it should insert otherwise update.

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery() returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed.  So when you do an insert and get a return value of zero it indicates the primary key is already in the table and you need to do an Update.  When you do an update and the return value is zero then it indicates the primary key is not in the table and you need to do an insert.

Comment: thanks a lot, i got it.